# Breaking chocolate bars game

Tags: recreational-mathematics, combinatorial-game-theory

About two weeks ago, a friend of mine taught me the following game without his knowing the answer. It may be famous, but I haven't known it.

There are $N\ (\in\mathbb N)$ chocolate bars composed of $a_i\times b_i\ (i=1,2,\cdots, N)$ squares of chocolate. Here, suppose that $a_i$ is the length of the vertical edge of each square, and that $b_i$ is the length of the horizontal edge of each square. Also, let $a_i,b_i$ be natural numbers. (see below. $N=4$ case.)

$\ \ \ \ $[image]

Two players $A, B$ take turns picking up a piece of chocolate and cutting it along the grid lines. A player cuts through and creates a new pieces. The first player $A$ always has to cut it **horizontally**. The second player $B$ always has to cut it **vertically**. One must not turn around the squares. A player that has no place to cut loses. (see below. $N=3$ case in which the game will be continued.)

$\ \ \ \ $[image]

**Examples** : If there is a chocolate bar composed of $3\times 2$ squares of chocolate, then the player $B$ wins. If there is a chocolate bar composed of $4\times 2$ squares of chocolate, then the player $A$ wins.

> **Question** : In what cases does the player $A$ win? Why?

I have a conjecture.

**My conjecture** : The player $A$ wins $\iff \sum_{i=1}^{N}\lfloor \log_2 a_i\rfloor\gt \sum_{i=1}^{N}\lfloor\log_2 b_i\rfloor$ holds.

This seems true for $N=1$ case and some other smaller cases, but I don't think I've succeeded in proving this strictly. Of course it may not be true. Can anyone help?

**Edit** : I edited the notation. I hope this time is not confusing.

Comment: It seems to me that you forgot to mention a condition for a valid cut, else a $2\times 4$ is won by $B$, since a has to cut the only horizontal line and $B$ has multiple options ($6$ vertical segments remain, $3$ each in a $1\times4$ subset of the original bar)...

Comment: @AlexR: 'The player $A$ wins' means that the player $A$ has a strategy to win no matter where the player $B$ cuts. In this sense, the player $A$ wins in the case of $2×4$. Also, I don't understand what you wrote in the parenthesis. For exmple, in the case of $2×2$, the first player $A$ has only one place to cut(the middle horizontal line segment whose length is $2$). And after the player $A$ cuts it, the player $B$ has only two places to cut.

Comment: This still makes no sense to me:

$$\begin{array}{c}\Box\Box\Box\Box\\\Box\Box\Box\Box\end{array}$$
Cut by $A$ into (only one possibility)
$$\begin{array}{c}\Box\Box\Box\Box\\\hline\\\Box\Box\Box\Box\end{array}$$
$B$ can chose from $6$ vertical segments (1-long lines) to cut...
After that, $A$ can't cut anything, because no horizontal pieces remain...

Comment: @AlexR: Please note that the number $2$ in $2\times 4$ represents the length of the horizontal edge of the rectangle.

Comment: Ah, nevermind. Your notation is really confusing. $B$ has to chose a line within $a_i$ tiles and $A$ within $b_i$... That was really confusing.

Comment: @AlexR: Thanks for pointing it out. I'll edit it.

Comment: Just for reference: a short discussion of this game, under the name "cutcake", can be found in *Winning Ways for your Mathematical Plays* (Academic Press, 1982) by Elwyn R. Berlekamp, John H. Conway, and Richard K. Guy.  The game is discussed in chapter 2 (page 24).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a combinatoric game. Using Conway notation, you can show that this game is always a number (cold game) and always an integer.

Let $A$ be the Left player and $B$ be the Right player.

Then show that the value $v$ of $(a,b)$ verifies :

1. $v(a,b)=-v(b,a)$
2. for $a\ge b$, let $|x|$ the number of bits in the binary representation of $x$ ($|0|=0$, $|1|=1$, $|2|=|3|=2$, |4|=|5|=|6|=|7|=3, etc). Then 
   $$v(a,b)=\left\lfloor\frac{a}{2^{|b|-1}}\right\rfloor-1 $$

So if $A$ begins, he has a winning strategy as long as long as $a\ge 2^{|b|}$ (he needs $v>0$ to win)

If there are several pieces :

$$\mbox{A has a winning strategy} \Longleftrightarrow \left(\sum_i v(a_i,b_i)\right)>0$$

---

Exemple of values :

$$\tiny\begin{array}{r|cc}
b_i\rightarrow& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16\\\hline
a_i=1&0 &-1 &-2 &-3 &-4 &-5 &-6 &-7 &-8 &-9 &-10 &-11 &-12 &-13 &-14 &-15\\
2&1 &0 &0 &-1 &-1 &-2 &-2 &-3 &-3 &-4 &-4 &-5 &-5 &-6 &-6 &-7 \\
3&2 &0 &0 &-1 &-1 &-2 &-2 &-3 &-3 &-4 &-4 &-5 &-5 &-6 &-6 &-7 \\
4&3 &1 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &-1 &-1 &-1 &-1 &-2 &-2 &-2 &-2 &-3 \\
5&4 &1 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &-1 &-1 &-1 &-1 &-2 &-2 &-2 &-2 &-3 \\
6&5 &2 &2 &0 &0 &0 &0 &-1 &-1 &-1 &-1 &-2 &-2 &-2 &-2 &-3 \\
7&6 &2 &2 &0 &0 &0 &0 &-1 &-1 &-1 &-1 &-2 &-2 &-2 &-2 &-3 \\
8&7 &3 &3 &1 &1 &1 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &-1 \\
9&8 &3 &3 &1 &1 &1 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &-1 \\
10&9 &4 &4 &1 &1 &1 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &-1 \\
11&10 &4 &4 &1 &1 &1 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &-1 \\
12&11 &5 &5 &2 &2 &2 &2 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &-1 \\
13&12 &5 &5 &2 &2 &2 &2 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &-1 \\
14&13 &6 &6 &2 &2 &2 &2 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &-1 \\
15&14 &6 &6 &2 &2 &2 &2 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &-1 \\
16&15 &7 &7 &3 &3 &3 &3 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &0  \end{array} $$

EDIT (long answer to a comment) :

Yes, this is a cold game, so each time a player plays, the situation become worse for him. So skipping his turn is good.

All those (cold) games can be represented by a number (not necessarily an integer, it could be a real, or an ordinal). Here the game is simple, and we only get integers.

So the integer value of the game is how many turn a player can skip  his turn and still lose. So if $v(a,b)=3$, $B$ can skip 3 times (assuming $B$ begins) and still lose (so this is a good game for $A$). The same for $v(a,b)=-3$ but you exchange $A$ and $B$. $v(a,b)=0$ means the first player will lose.

Usually, to compute the value of a situation $s$, we compute all values of all situations any player can go from $s$, and use the usual theory to infer the initial value (again "On numbers and games"). But you're right in your remarks and perhaps you can simply prove the values by reasoning on "how many times first player can cut at first without losing". But I guess you will just have to rebuild the theory in this particular case. You can't do without it on such games. Read the book !

Comment: Thanks. So, for $N\in\mathbb N$ in general, you are saying that the player $A$ wins $\iff \sum_{i=1}^{N}\{\lfloor a_i/2^{|b_i|-1}\rfloor-1\}\gt 0$, aren't you?

Comment: @mathlove Yes, if there are several pieces, the sum (of the values of each piece) must be positive. This is not exactly as your conjecture. And remember that if $a_i<b_i$, the value is $1-\lfloor \frac{b_i}{2^{|a_i|-1}}\rfloor$.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem I've been facing is that I have no idea how to prove that $v(a_i,b_i)=\lfloor a_i/2^{|b_i|-1}\rfloor-1$ when $a_i\ge b_i$ and that $v(a_i,b_i)=1-\lfloor b_i/2^{|a_i|-1}\rfloor$ when $a_i\lt b_i$. Can you please show me how?

Comment: @mathlove. By induction. You just need to see that $v(a,b)=v(2a,2b)=v(2a,2b+1)=v(2a+1,2b)=v(2a+1,2b+1)$. And $v(n,1)=-v(1,n)=n-1$. The difficult step is to realise that cutting along a border is always bad. But you need to be familiar with the Conway theory (read "On numbers and games" by J.H.Conway).

Comment: Thank you for letting me know the book! By the way, I don't think I can get the player $A$'s winning strategy when $\sum_i v(a_i,b_i)\gt 0$. Can you please tell me about it?

Comment: @mathlove : any good move for A is a move that only drop the value by 1 (because B will have to (at least) add 1 on his turn. This is always possible when the value is positive. From that and the table, you can deduce you always can do that by choosing any piece $(a,b)$ with $a\ge 2^{|b|}$ and remove a (almost) square $(2^{|b|-1},b)$. You're sure to win easily.

Comment: @mathlove and by "remove" I mean split of course :) or cut...

Comment: The winning strategy does work! Thanks! By the way, I'm facing difficulty in proving that $v(a,b)$ is represented in that way by induction. I have two questions. First, what is $v(a,b)$ in the first place? Second, how can we prove $v(a,b)=v(2a,2b)=v(2a,2b+1)=\cdots$ as you wrote? (I'm going to write my understanding about $v(a,b)$. For example, $v(8,2)=3$ implies that $A$ has a winning strategy even if two players cut in order of $AAABABABABA$. So, $v(a,b)\ (a\ge b)$ represents the maximum times that $A$ can cut first. Can I use this understanding(or definition) to prove $v(a,b)$?)

Comment: @mathlove I edited my answer to answer your last comment.

Answer (score 2):

This game is called Cutcake, and it is explicitly analyzed in both "On Numbers and Games" and "Winning Ways". (For some reason the spam-blocker thinks this answer is spam; not sure why.)

Comment: Welcome to M.SE. It may help to elaborate on the answers you give so that you answer the question that is being asked.

Comment: @thkim1011, do you know who Jim Propp is?  "Well known expert visits Math.SE, leaves excellent answer, and receives the newbie presumed-idiot treatment with canned comment replies" does not reflect well on the site.

Comment: @ASCIIAdvocate I suppose that [this guy](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/260701/leonhard-euler) is really the great Euler himself.  You cannot assume that, simply because someone claims to be a great expert, that they really are who they claim.  That said, if this really is James Propp, I'm quite excited to have someone of his stature on this site. :)

Comment: @apnorton, and you cannot reasonably assume that I am assuming that.  In fact I am not (drawing conclusions only from a username, which is what "simply because someone claims..." appears to mean ).  ((ah. I see you edited the comment to add the third sentence.  But my preceding comment does hold.))

Comment: @ASCIIAdvocate Wow I had no idea. Sorry to Jim Propp. It's interesting how the situation would differ if the poster was a different person.

Comment: @thkim1011, as suggested in the first comment I left, I think this style of  "welcome" messages is out of place for practically any other user, too.  Sorry to JP for picking up on his answer as a place to call out that practice, but really, M.SE is going the way of Wikipedia with the pointless bureaucracy.