# chocolate breaking game

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory

This question is based on a high school entry exam many years ago in my country, maybe it's famous but i didnt found the source.

In the beginning there is a chocolate bar size $m\times n$ on the table, in each step the player will pick a chocolate piece and break them into two smaller piece with integer side length (i.e they can either break into ($m\times a$ and $m\times(n-a)$ bar) **or** ($n\times b$ and $n\times(m-b)$ bar) with $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}^+, 0<a<n,0<b<m$). Whoever make the first chocolate piece of size $1\times 1$ will lose, find the winner.

I have struggled this problem for quite a while, although the original version is much easier (they given $mn$ are even), when they are both odd, even in the case $m=1$ it is still very difficult I have try this by hand for the first 20 value and find out:

For $m = 1$ and $n<20$ the player who play after will win if and only if $n = 7,11,17$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Breaking chocolate bars game](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874668/breaking-chocolate-bars-game)

Comment: How familiar are you with NIMbers? Or [combinatorial games](https://brilliant.org/wiki/combinatorial-games-definition/)?

Comment: @Imsteffan Not quite. That post has the restriction of vertical/horizontal cuts for each individual.

Comment: I've often seen the trick question variant of this, where the first person who cannot make a move loses. In that case the game ends when the chocolate has been split into $mn$ unit blocks. This will always take $mn-1$ moves, since each move creates one more piece. Therefore the first person wins when $mn$ is even, and second person wins when $mn$ is odd. The version in this question is harder and does indeed seem to require the calculation of NIMbers.

Comment: We can rephrase the rules to say that creating $1\times 1$ pieces is forbidden, and you lose if you cannot make any legal moves. Then the $1\times n$ bar is equivalent to the [octal game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal_game) $0.4$ with $n-1$ tokens, which I suspect is equivalent to some more standard octal game like Dawson's Kayles.

Comment: @Imsteffan the rule on that game is different, in here they can break in arbitrary way not necessary forced horizontally or vertically

Comment: @MishaLavrov can you tell me more information about that 0.4 game ?